# Save select values in an array and go through it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 6 select fields to select three different options ("Please Select..", "Yes" and "No"). I want to be able to know which values has been selected inside a group, each group of select is inside a div. I try using this:

```
 $('#qqq').find('select').change(function () {
         //  alert($(this).val());
        var option = $(this).val();
        selectValues.push($(this).val());
```

But this only works when you change the value, and don´t storage the values, therefore if you go through the group in other order the results are different. For example if you start in the last select and then go in inverse order. Pushing the values into a variable, the values are saved but if you change twice is saved it twice in "selectValues"
My html is something like this:

```
<div class="mygroup">
 <select id="aa">
 <select id="bb">
 <select id="cc">
</div>
```

The values of the select are generated in jQuery, therefore the values can be retrieve using --> this.val()

**My question is how can I retrieve the values of a group and then go through it?** I had though in save it in an array and then go through it, but I don't know if the array values are going to change when you change the select twice.

*I want to know it, because if any of the select is "Yes", some below input fields should be required and if all of them are "No", those fields should be readonly.*

Comment: How do you change the order of the selects? Is it a drag and drop? And how many exactly are in each group?

Comment: I think you must re-phrase your post and highlight your question, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
var curVals = {};
$('#qqq').find('select').each(function () {
    curVals[$(this).prop('id')] = $(this).val();
});
```

or this:

```
var $selectedYes = $('#qqq').find('select').filter(function () {
    return $(this).val().toLowerCase() === 'yes';
});
```

If any have 'Yes' then `$selectedYes` will be a `jQuery` object containing only those `select` element(s); if none are, it will be an empty `jQuery` object.

Comment: I´m using this and works perfectly, but I don´t know how to know if there are any Yes or no here. `var arrayOfValues = $('#quest').find('select').map(function (i, el) { return $(el).val(); }).get();`

Comment: `if ($selectedYes.length) { /* there are some */} else { /* there are none */}`